# ADODB.Stream 3002 File Could Not Be Opened

Tags: excel, stream, adodb, vba

**Why am I getting 'File could not be opened?' error in ADODB.Stream**

*Problem*

I'm currently getting `Run-time error '3002': File could not be opened` on the below line `FileStream.LoadFromFile fileCurrent.Path`.

*What I've Tried*

- Making sure the path is valid

  - Using the immediate window, I can see that `?fileCurrent.Path` =
    `C:\Users\(puzzlepiece87)\Desktop\Test.txt`
- Using a fresh text file

  - I created Test.txt as a blank file in which I typed "Hello", pushed Enter, typed "Goodbye", and then saved as the ANSI default.
- Making sure the procedure being in a class module didn't hurt anything

  - I tried it in a standard module as well
- I tried moving it out of Personal.xlsb to a standard workbook

  - Using a standard workbook had the same issue

*Remaining Questions*

- What am I doing wrong that is causing the 3002 error?
- Am I misunderstanding `.LoadFromFile`'s `FileName` parameter? It says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/loadfromfile-method-ado) that it will accept any valid path and name in UNC format.

**Class Module classReallyBigFiles**

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub ReadLargeFile(ByVal fileCurrent As Scripting.File)

    Dim FileStream As ADODB.Stream
    Set FileStream = New ADODB.Stream
    FileStream.Type = adTypeText
    FileStream.LineSeparator = adCRLF
    FileStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
    FileStream.Open
    FileStream.LoadFromFile fileCurrent.Path
    MsgBox FileStream.ReadText(-2)
    FileStream.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: When I create `fileCurrent` with `Set fileCurrent = fs.GetFile("C:\Users\(puzzlepiece87)\Desktop\Text.txt")` your code runs without error. The MsgBox displays `???????` (not sure what that's about).

Comment: @xidgel Sadly I got the same error this time. I added the following: `    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject`
    `Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject`

    `Dim fileCurrent2 As Scripting.File`
    `Set fileCurrent2 = FSO.GetFile("C:\Users\(puzzlepiece87)\Desktop\Test.txt")` and changed it to `.LoadFromFile fileCurrent2.path`. I'll try restarting my computer again.

Comment: A brief search for the 3002 error suggests the file may be corrupted. Did you try deleting and re-creating Text.txt?

Comment: @xidgel It was another dumb thing instead. I MCVE'd too hard and left out the part where I was opening the file as Binary, then trying ADODB.Stream when the file was too big to save the contents to a string, but I forgot to close the Binary attempt first. If you post an answer along the lines of "This error will show up if it is already open elsewhere. Make sure you're not pre-opening it via another method." I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @xidgel Also, for the record, now that it's working for me, I'm getting the same `???????` in the Msgbox also. If I find out what that's about I'll let you know.

Comment: Sounds like you deserve the credit for solving the problem.

Comment: @xidgel Having someone else say "it works for me" was valuable to me. It helped broaden the search. Thanks regardless of what you decide.

Comment: @xidgel I needed a `.CharSet = "UTF-8"`. So ?????? appears when the encoding isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I MCVE'd too hard and left out the part where I was opening the file as Binary, then trying ADODB.Stream when the file was too big to save the entire file contents to a string by that method, but I had forgotten to close the Binary attempt first.